# onRegistered() is called but onMessage() not

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have the below two methods in the class GCMIntentService, however the onRegistered() method gets called upon registeration for regID, however, when I send a message the onMessage() does not get called.

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)
{
    Log.i(tag, "onRegistered called");
    GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    sendNotification("A", "B");
}
```

below is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.myApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.myApp.GCMIntentService" />
```

I am getting the registration ID like this :

```
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            //Check if we have registered.
            if (regid.length() == 0) {
                GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(myActivity.this);
                GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(myActivity.this);
                GCMRegistrar.register(myActivity.this, SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                Log.i(tag, "You are already registered.");
                Log.i(tag, "The registration ID is : " + regid);
            }
```

Comment: So how do you send message to your GCM registered device? Is there any script in PHP or else?

Comment: Yes using PHP as server side. The php shows that it is being sent fine to android. The issue is in my receiving in android.

Comment: Can you show me your code where your registration id is getting?

Comment: Its fine.. I think you should cross verify with your server data where you are registering your reg id. I think web service you are calling after registration is not working well to add id in database.

Comment: I manually checked the DB and it is there...

Comment: http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-send-message-to-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-server-using-json-and-php/.. check this link, which has ready made php script to send push notification. Just replace reg id with your one. And run it.

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

But you forgot this:

```
 <permission android:name="com.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Comment: the way I see it looks fine, what do u mean ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest, use the below code to receive message:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.MyApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.MyApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```